# The "Schema.Types." prefix: "Schema.Types.ObjectId" versus "ObjectId" in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

In the [Mongoose SchemaTypes doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), they list these valid SchemaTypes:

String
Number
Date
Buffer
Boolean
Mixed
Objectid
Array

In the example they have:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  name:    String,
  binary:  Buffer,
  living:  Boolean,
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  age:     { type: Number, min: 18, max: 65 }
  mixed:   Schema.Types.Mixed,
  _someId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ...
})
```

If `String`, `Buffer`, `Boolean`, `Mixed`, and `ObjectId` are all listed under SchemaTypes, how come only `Mixed` and `ObjectId` are prefixed with `Schema.Types.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gkatsev from #Node.js irc answers:

Only Mixed and ObjectId aren't built in so they need the prefix, as explained in the ["Usage Notes" section](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).